# Setup hadoop map-reduce job to retieve data from Cassandra database

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I have setup `Cassandra` across four clusters and `hadoop` on two clusters and now I want to setup map reduce job so that it can retrieve data from `Casandra` database and do analytic stuff. Can anyone tell me step by step procedure to implement word count example here ? like which configuration files to change and how do I point my `Cassandra` data directory for map-reduce job ?

Comment: I am using CQL. but currently I am stuck at running ant in word count example as explained in README.TXT file in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pig for analysis data. 
http://frommyworkshop.blogspot.com/2012/07/single-node-hadoop-cassandra-pig-setup.html